# Cellular basis of two isomorphic group algebras

Tags: gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, geometric-group-theory

Let $W_1, W_2$ be two groups and $\varphi: W_1 \to W_2$ a group isomorphism. For a commutative Noetherian integral domain $R$, we have a $R$-linear isomorphism $\overline{\varphi}: R[W_1] \to R[W_2]$.

Suppose that $R[W_1]$ is a cellular algebra with cell basis $\{c_1, \ldots, c_n\}$. Whether $\{\overline{\varphi}(c_1), \ldots, \overline{\varphi}(c_n)\}$ is a cell basis of $R[W_2]$?

I know that $\{\overline{\varphi}(c_1), \ldots, \overline{\varphi}(c_n)\}$ is a $R$-basis of $R[W_2]$.

Comment: @ Geoff Robinson For any $a, b \in R$, we have $ab=ba$.

Comment: A group isomorphism induces an isomorphism of group rings that, in particular, respects the $R$-algebra multiplication. So, $\overline{\varphi}$ will send a cellular basis of $R[W_1]$ to a cellular basis of $R[W_2]$. Here I assume that you mean cellular in the sense of Graham and Lehrer.

Comment: @ Andrew  Yes, I mean cellular in the sense of Graham and Lehrer. Let $\{c_i \mid i\in I\}$ be a cellular basis of  $R[W_1]$. I am not sure if $\{\overline{\varphi}(c_i) \mid i \in I \}$ satisfies condition (3) defined in [Cellular algebras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cellular_algebra). Thank you very much.

Comment: @Geoff Robinson Thank you for pointing out the mistake.

Comment: Condition (C3) holds in $R[W_1]$. Now apply $\overline{\varphi}$ and use the fact that it respects linearity and multiplication in the algebra. You might be worried about whether $\overline{\varphi}$ intertwines the $*$ involution but this is immediate as you *define* the $*$ involution for $R[W_2]$ to be the map that sends $\overline{\varphi}(C^\lambda_{ST})$ to $\overline{\varphi}(C^\lambda_{TS})$.

Comment: @ Andrew  Ok, I got it. Thank you very much.